# Add simple graphics on top of default Holo theme?

Tags: android, xml, image, graphics, line

I've gone through almost all of the android developers page, as well as stackoverflow, but cannot seem to find a straightforward answer. My app uses the default holo.light theme, and all I want to add is a simple line dividing the app about 2/3 of the way down. I still want to keep the holo theme though. Just a line across the middle. Do I have to make the image myself, or can I do that right in the xml? Doing it right in the xml would be a lot easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I still want to keep the holo theme though

A dividing line would have nothing to do with the theme.

> Do I have to make the image myself

Well, the line has to come from somewhere. That could be a nine-patch PNG file in an `ImageView`, or a background color on a `View`, or a `ShapeDrawable` background on a `View`, etc. Only you know what you want your line to look like.

> can I do that right in the xml?

You can define the `View` or `ImageView` in your layout XML. If you choose to create a nine-patch PNG file to serve as the image, that you would have to create yourself, using a combination of a graphics editor and the **`draw9patch`** utility.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure how I would go about doing that. From what I've read, the View/ImageView seems like the easiest way to do it. Could you recommend me a link or a certain page for more info?

Comment: @user3183598: More info for... what? Layout resources and how to use them is covered in the developer documentation. `android:background` is documented on `View`. FWIW, here is a sample `TableLayout`, in which I have a thin blue line running across the middle: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Containers/Table/res/layout/main.xml